# Smart table column with action attached

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using a Smart Table in my SAPUI5 app with no custom columns, so all the columns are coming from OData. One column should be like a link, so if user presses the data in the column, it should open up a dialog or fragment to navigate further or execute an action. So two questions, I have not been able to figure out:

1. How to format a column which is not a custom column, as a link?
2. Have an action on the column (like `CellClick` or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can in the XML view redefine smarttable columns using CustomData, here a [SAP blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/26/different-ways-of-adding-custom-columns-to-smart-table-in-sapui5/)
2. You can use a [sap.m.Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Link) or a [sap.m.Button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button) inside the cell or by adding an event listener when the row is clicked like attachItemPress

---

```
<smartTable:SmartTable>    
  <Table>
   <columns>
      <Column>
        <customData>
          <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "yourKey", "leadingProperty": "yourLeadingProperty", "columnIndex": theIndex}'/>
        </customData>
        <Text text="{i18n>YourPropertyName}"></Text>
      </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
      <ColumnListItem>
        <Link text="{LinkText}" href="YourLink"/>
      </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
  </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```